# How to solve xapian-core issues in Ubuntu 11.10

Tags: ruby, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-3.2, xapian

I am unable to install the gem xapian-core in Ubuntu 11.10 (GNU/Linux 3.0.0-16-virtual i686) with gcc 4.6.1
    My ruby version is 1.9.2 and rails 3.2.3.
    It is saying that C compiler cannot create executables.

```
See config.log for more details.

I am trying to install  xapian-core for my ruby application. It works everything fine in older version of Ubuntu 10.10. But when I require to upload all the files to server(Ubuntu 11.10) there it through s an issue with following error.

xapian-bindings-1.2.7/perl/Search/Xapian/PositionIterator.pm
xapian-bindings-1.2.7/perl/Search/Xapian/PostingIterator.pm
xapian-bindings-1.2.7/perl/Search/Xapian/QueryParserError.pm
xapian-bindings-1.2.7/perl/Search/Xapian/QueryParser.pm
xapian-bindings-1.2.7/perl/Search/Xapian/Query.pm
xapian-bindings-1.2.7/perl/Search/Xapian/RangeError.pm
xapian-bindings-1.2.7/perl/Search/Xapian/RSet.pm
xapian-bindings-1.2.7/perl/Search/Xapian/RuntimeError.pm
xapian-bindings-1.2.7/perl/Search/Xapian/SimpleStopper.pm
xapian-bindings-1.2.7/perl/Search/Xapian/Stem.pm
xapian-bindings-1.2.7/perl/Search/Xapian/Stopper.pm
xapian-bindings-1.2.7/perl/Search/Xapian/TermGenerator.pm
xapian-bindings-1.2.7/perl/Search/Xapian/TermIterator.pm
xapian-bindings-1.2.7/perl/Search/Xapian/TradWeight.pm
xapian-bindings-1.2.7/perl/Search/Xapian/UnimplementedError.pm
xapian-bindings-1.2.7/perl/Search/Xapian/ValueIterator.pm
xapian-bindings-1.2.7/perl/Search/Xapian/Weight.pm
xapian-bindings-1.2.7/perl/Search/Xapian/WritableDatabase.pm
xapian-bindings-1.2.7/perl/Search/Xapian.pm
xapian-bindings-1.2.7/perl/t/
xapian-bindings-1.2.7/perl/t/symbol-test/
xapian-bindings-1.2.7/perl/t/symbol-test/SymbolTest.pm
xapian-bindings-1.2.7/perl/t/symbol-test/typemap
xapian-bindings-1.2.7/perl/t/symbol-test/SymbolTest.xs
xapian-bindings-1.2.7/perl/t/symbol-test/Makefile.PL
xapian-bindings-1.2.7/lua/docs/
xapian-bindings-1.2.7/lua/docs/examples/
xapian-bindings-1.2.7/lua/docs/examples/simpleindex.lua
xapian-bindings-1.2.7/lua/docs/examples/simpleexpand.lua
xapian-bindings-1.2.7/lua/docs/examples/simplematchdecider.lua
xapian-bindings-1.2.7/lua/docs/examples/simplesearch.lua
xapian-bindings-1.2.7/lua/docs/index.html
xapian-bindings-1.2.7/lua/Makefile.am
xapian-bindings-1.2.7/lua/Makefile.in
xapian-bindings-1.2.7/lua/util.i
xapian-bindings-1.2.7/lua/smoketest.lua
xapian-bindings-1.2.7/lua/xapian_wrap.cc
prefix = /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/xapian-core-1.2.7.1
./configure --prefix=/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/xapian-core-1.2.7.1 --exec-prefix=/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/xapian-core-1.2.7.1
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /bin/mkdir -p
checking for gawk... no
checking for mawk... mawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking how to create a ustar tar archive... gnutar
checking build system type... i686-pc-linux-gnu
checking host system type... i686-pc-linux-gnu
checking how to print strings... printf
checking for style of include used by make... GNU
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... no
configure: error: in `/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/xapian-core-1.2.7.1/ext/xapian-core-1.2.7':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details
rake aborted!


Tasks: TOP => default
(See full trace by running task with --trace)


Gem files will remain installed in /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/xapian-core-1.2.7.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/xapian-core-1.2.7.1/ext/gem_make.out

An error occured while installing xapian-core (1.2.7.1), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install xapian-core -v '1.2.7.1'` succeeds before bundling.


When I am trying to install "xapian-core" it was not allowing to install .

Can any once please help me for this issue. How can I proceed with xapian package for Ubuntu 11.10.

 Can any one plz provide me the step by step procedure of installing this package.
```

Comment: This seems like a problem with your compiler. What is the output in config.log for that test?

Answer (score 2):

You can checkout the latest version from github and build it on your own.
Step by step follows.

1. Checkout the latest Version:
   `git clone https://github.com/rlane/xapian-full.git`
   `cd xapian-full`
2. Build the gem:
   `rake`
   `gem build xapian-full.gemspec`
3. Install it:
   `gem install --local xapian-full*.gem`